# Crashing when using DBI Schedule gantt chart

Tags: winforms, dbi, gantt-chart

We're having random crashes when using the DBI Schedule control which is a gantt chart. Below is the stack trace:

```
************** Exception Text **************
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and     less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
   at System.Collections.CollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Dbi.WinControl.Schedule.ScheduleCollection.get_Item(Int32 nIndex)
   at Dbi.WinControl.Schedule.dbiSchedule.GuideLineBarSnap(Point ptPoint)
   at Dbi.WinControl.Schedule.dbiSchedule.MoveAllTimeBar(Point ptPoint, MouseEventArgs e)
   at Dbi.WinControl.Schedule.dbiSchedule.OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Anyone else had issues like this?

Comment: Yes! I'm having the problem right now, but I don't have a solution. Did you ever get it figured out?

Answer (score 0):

My error showed up by doing the following on a schedule:
1. Create an appointment
2. Double-click appointment (this brought up window that allowed you to do several things, one of which was to delete the appointment)
3. Delete the appointment
4. Save
5. ERROR

I think the problem was that while it's going through callbacks, the schedule control only keeps track of which appointment it's working with by the index associated with it. After the appointment was deleted, it would move up the callback chain to the OnMouseUp event (analogous to your OnMouseMove event). Upon finding no appointment at the index it used for the double-click event, it would spit out the same error you were getting.

My solution was, unfortunately, a bit of a hack, but the application needed to get done quick and it worked: Within the double-click event, after a delete occurred, I added an appointment in place of the old one, but with a start and end date of our standard NULL date (as a flag that this is just a dummy appointment). I then made an override of the OnMouseUp event which just called the base class's OnMouseUp event, then searched for and deleted the dummy appointment.

Given that you originally posted this almost a year ago, it's probably not useful to you, but hopefully it will help someone.

Comment: We've moved on now from using this Control so I can't check! Thanks for your response though.